# DJango Python File Upload how to preserve orginal file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload a file using Rest to a DJango Python API. But I noticed the file gets modified. Specifically a content-disposition is added to it.  I haven't found a good way to remove this. The problem is I am trying to upload a tar that needs to be unzipped, but the modified content prevents unzipping the file.

I’m using this file parser on a rest page:
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser

The following code seems to get the file for me in the post method of an APIView

```
file_obj = request.FILES['file']
scanfile.file.save(file_obj.name, file_obj)
```

Where scanfile is a model with a file field.
The file gets saved with contents like this:

```
--b3c91a6c13e34fd5a1e253b1a72d63b3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sometar.tgz"
My tar file contents here.....
--b3c91a6c13e34fd5a1e253b1a72d63b3
```

My client looks like this:

```
filename = "sometar.tgz"
exclusion = "../../exclusionlist.txt"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;’,
           'Authorization': 'JWT %s' % token,
           }
url = "http://localhost:%s/api/scan/Project/%s/" % (port, filename)
#files = {'file': open(filename, 'rb'), 'exclusion_file': open(exclusion, 'rb')}  # also tried this way but it just put the info in the same file and I see the headers in the file
files = [('file', open(filename, 'rb')), ('file', open(exclusion, 'rb'))]
x = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

So my question is how do I remove that content-disposition info from the saved file so I can properly unzip the file?

Answer (score 0):

`request.FILES['file']` is an [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) object. You can get its name with `request.FILES['file'].name` and get just the content with `request.FILES['file'].read()`.

You should be careful with `read()` and big files:

> Read the entire uploaded data from the file. Be careful with this
>   method: if the uploaded file is huge it can overwhelm your system if
>   you try to read it into memory. You’ll probably want to use chunks()
>   instead; see below.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile

Comment: I have tried with .read() and .chunks() as well and either way the file still has the content-disposition tag in it.

Comment: I have a work around but it involves manually removing lines: with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
            lines = file_obj.readlines()
            tmp.writelines(lines[3:-1])
            tmp.seek(0)

Comment: I tried read() again and get an error. So that is why I didn't use it.   File "/utils.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' code is now scanfile.file.save(file_obj.name, file_obj.read()) but it appears to be a string not a UploadedFile. scanfile is still file_obj = request.FILES['file']

Comment: Try not explicitly setting `Content-Type` and letting requests handle it for you. Also try two different file names, otherwise Django might only show one. Other than that, try using Wireshark or some other debugging tool to verify the request is what you expect it to be.